# Create Dynamic Query in EF

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, datagridview

I explain my problem with an example. (Entity Framework and VB.net 2012)

I have two DataGridViews in my form. first DGV populated from a table in SQL (datasource) and second DGV datasource is an empty table in SQL (By Entitiy Faramwork). user must selects some records from DGV1 and sends them to DGV2 by clicking on a button.

and what is the problem?

when user sends some records from DGV1 to DGV2, transferred records must eliminate from DGV1 without any change on SQL tables. changes finally will be saved by a button clicking.

How can create this relation between DGV1 and DGV2 datasources with out any change to main data in SQL??

I can do this easily in MS Access but i cant do this in EF.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what your query looks like? At you familiar with lambda expressions?

Comment: what type of form is this? A Web Form or Windows Form?